# Android 2.1 WebView AJAX requests

Tags: android, ajax, dynamic, webview

I have a Android 2.1 application with a WebView. In that WebView I want to load a HTML file from the APK's assets folder itself. I've read how in Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can intercept requests and formulate your own response.

What I want to do is supply a dataset to the webview dynamically without having to reload the page. How would I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably skip the AJAX request and just use [`addJavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Felix, I have a Javascript interface added, which handles data in the page, but the return has to be given through a WebView.loadUrl() each and every time. I want to do it AJAX-like to avoid having to reload the page.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't define a method in that instance that loads the required data, call it from Javascript and do whatever you want with the data, such as insert it into the current page? I have not tried this / never done it, but that's how I imagine it would work.

Comment: it works in that I define a method in the instance to load the required data. Now I only have a few JavaScript related problems to fix, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `myWebView.loadData(... HTML String ...)`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: that eventually navigates away from the page I have open, which isn't what I need. It's a good suggestion though.